# Confusing error with generic container in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider this code:

```js
class Base {}

class Foo<T extends Base> {
  constructor(public callback: (data: T) => void) {
  }
}

let map: Map<number, Foo<Base>> = new Map();

function rpcCall<T extends Base>(
  callback: (data: T) => void,
): void {
  map.set(0, new Foo<T>(callback));
}
```

It gives me this error:

> Argument of type `Foo<T>` is not assignable to parameter of type `Foo<Base>`.
>
> Type `Base` is not assignable to type `T`.
>
> `Base` is assignable to the constraint of type `T`, but `T` could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint `Base`.

I can't see why this shouldn't work. The error message seems correct, but I don't see why that is an error. I *want* `T` to be allowed to be a different subtype of constraint `Base`.

Also, this *does* work:

```js
class Base { }

class Foo<T extends Base> {
  constructor(public callback: (data: T) => void) {
  }
}

class Foo2<T extends Base> {
}

let map: Map<number, Foo<Base> | Foo2<Base>> = new Map();

function rpcCall<T extends Base>(
  callback: (data: T) => void,

): void {
  map.set(0, new Foo<T>(callback));
}
```

Comment: What is your plan for handling this: `class BaseWithRaisins extends Base { raisins = 100; } rpcCall((x: BaseWithRaisins) => console.log(x.raisins.toFixed())); map.get(0)!.callback(new Base());`?  That will throw no compile-time errors, but you will explode at runtime, since a `Foo<Base>`'s callback must accept *any* `Base`, but you gave it something that will only handle a `BaseWithRaisins`.

Comment: You *might* want to have `map` be a `Map<number, Foo<any>>`, but I don't see what you'll actually be able to *do* with it.  Presumably your use case somewhere involves pulling things out of the `map` and calling the callbacks, at which point you'll be stuck not knowing what types of argument it accepts.  Could you provide a fuller use case with example code for how you expect to use the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to add some properties to your code to illustrate this.

```
interface Base {
    bar: string;
}

interface Child extends Base {
    magic: number;
}

class Foo<T extends Base> {
    constructor(public callback: (data: T) => void) {
        // '{ bar: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',
        // but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Base'.
        callback({ bar: "sweet" });
    }
}

let map: Map<number, Foo<Base>> = new Map();

rpcCall((d: Child) => d.magic);

function rpcCall<T extends Base>(callback: (data: T) => void) {
    // 'Base' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',
    // but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Base'
    map.set(0, new Foo(callback));
}
```

Oh dear. More errors!

As you can see, inside `Foo` I attempted to call the callback you defined, and passed it an object that extends `Base`, but it threw an error back at me.

What if the callback is expecting a `Child`? Sure, anything that extends `Base` is fine as far as `Foo` cares, but how do you know what the callback itself is expecting?

If you take a look at my usage of `rpcCall` where I legally gave it a callback expecting a `Child`, I am trying to use the `magic` property (which is marked as required in my `Child extends Base` interface).

Basically at some point there might be an attempt to use something that does *not* exist on `Base`.

If you replaced the generics with simply `Base` would make some of the errors would go away, but doing something like `rpcCall((d: Child) => d.magic)` would be disallowed. If you don't need non-base properties in these areas, this might be ok for you.

---

The second version you provided works because `Foo2` is an empty class (the generic is completely ignored, in fact, since you don't use it).

An empty class is equivalent to `{}`, which basically accepts everything except `null` and `undefined` (as far as I am aware). And when it comes to union types, any "looser" parameter will take precedence over the more stringent ones.

The below are all equivalent (in this case):

```
Map<number, Foo<Base> | Foo2<Base>>
Map<number, Foo<Base> | {}>
Map<number, Foo<Foo2<Base>>
Map<number, Foo<{}>
```

In fact, if you piped `| any` to the end of any union, that union effectively becomes `any`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a valid error. Under `--strictFunctionTypes` function type parameter positions are checked contravariantly.

If TS allowed you to pass a function that requires an arbitrary subtype of `Base`, the `Foo` constructor would still be able to call it with just a plain `Base`, and the function expecting a specific subtype would fail.

You can disable `--strictFunctionTypes` to make your code compile, but you'll lose some type safety, per above. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html for details.